# Is it possible to run the android app on ChromeOS?

Tags: android, google-chrome-os, androidappsonchromeos

I need to check my app on a tablet, I have one which is Google Pixel Slate since it runs on ChromeOS, I am not sure if is it possible to run the app directly from the Android Studio on this device. Does anyone try this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/development-environment

Comment: @CommonsWare could you please take a look on this (related) question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73689284/android-studio-dont-see-pixel-slate-chromeos