# Android studio don't see Pixel Slate (ChromeOS)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-chrome-os, androidappsonchromeos

I need to test my android app on the tablet, the one I have is Pixel Slate which is running on Chrome OS, so in order to enable it for the developers and be able to run directly from the Android Studio I went throw these docs

https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/development-environment

I enabled Linux as well as ADB in the Developer Options, however, still, when I connect my Pixel Slate to my MacBook it doesn't appear in the list of the devices...

What am I missing here?

PS I have Mac M1

**UPD**

command `adb devices` shows - `zsh: command not found: adb`

**UPD2**

I connect my ChromeOS tablet and in Developers -> Manage USB devices there is a list of connected devices where I can see my MacBook Pro enabled, however, if I run `adb devices` in the terminal on my MacBook, the list of devices is still empty.

Comment: What does `adb devices` on your Mac show?

Comment: @CommonsWare updated in the question

Comment: `adb` can be found in the `platform-tools` directory of your Android SDK installation.

Comment: @CommonsWare updated in the question, could you please take a look?